# How to avoid getting bulk registrations?

Tags: user

I'm receiving a lot of bulk registrations from emails which don't correspond with the name, probably generated from a list on my joomla pages. How to prevent it? It is any danger behind that?

Comment: You can always add ReCapctha to your registration page which will prevent a lot of spam

Comment: What do you mean by "emails which don't correspond with the name?" My name and my email address are very very different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are likely spammers which try to use your system. If you have a forum, you will see them posting nice texts about some pharma and shoes :-D

If you don't need the user registration, you can shut it down in the configuration.
If you need it, you can add some spam plugins which will block the registration based on spam lists.
There is a whole category on JED listing those extensions: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/spam-protection

Answer (score 6):

Besides setting Global config to not allow registration, I highly recommend using something like Akeeba Admin Tools. These tools provide high levels of protection for Joomla sites.

I also have had good results using CloudFlare to buffer traffic to our sites. It keeps most of the bad traffic from ever even hitting the server. But installing Akeeba Admin Tools are the first step I take with every site.

One thing to consider is that all those spam registrations are only the tip of the iceberg. Most Joomla sites are targets for a wide range of spam and hack attempts. Those attempts consume bandwidth and server processing power. To say nothing of what happens if one of them gets into your site.
 -a-

Comment: As much as I agree with you about Admin Tools being a brilliant extension, I'm pretty sure it won't help prevent spam

Comment: I think Lodder is probably right. Admin Tools secures your website from various hack attempts. Not sure what I was thinking before. Anyway extensions that use Akismet or Project Honeypot are good for preventing spam/unwanted visitors.

Answer (score 5):

Try it whit recaptcha to protect your site against spam registrants:

1. Go to this Link and follow and create your recaptcha keys
   https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html
2. Go to http://youdomain.xyz/administrator/index.php?option=com_plugins and activate the recaptcha Plugin and put your private and public keys in the plugin settings
3. Then go to http://youdomain.xyz/administrator/index.php?option=com_config and set your Default Captcha to recaptcha
4. Then check http://youdomain.xyz/administrator/index.php?option=com_config&view=component&component=com_users if the Captcha Setting is "Default or recaptcha"
5. Check http://youdomain.xyz/index.php?option=com_users if the captcha works

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answers, a few more ideas in the case you still need the registration on your website: 
You could set up a custom registration form, with enabled other antispam features like captcha and hidden fields, add extra validation fields, set-up ip block  by countries, if your website is not intended for specific countries only.

Answer (score 3):

Bulk registration is a big issue for any website. We were facing the same issue, but using captcha is not an option because it hurts to genuine user.

We started to use

1. [CloudFlare](http://CloudFlare.com) : Helped us from bots, also have firewall to protect against known joomla attacks.
2. [Fail2Ban](http://www.fail2ban.org) : Can block user when they perform certain action n-times.

These helped a lot in keeping spam away, and registration simple for our users.
We have shared it in a [blog](http://www.readybytes.net/blog/item/improving-speed-of-joomla-based-website.html).

> Security and Spam protection : For this crucial subject we are currently relying on Fail2ban and Cloudflare. They help us in securing our servers and applications from malicious hacking attempts as well as spams. There respective task lists includes the following.
>
> - Fail2ban observes server logs and blocks the suspicious hackers and spammers.
> - Cloudflare has a real-time firewall installed to protect the applications from exploits, XSS, SQL injection attacks.
> - Cloudflare can identify spam users by browser integrity checks and block them as well.